# Subversion post commit to tags hook

Tags: windows, svn, tags, svn-hooks

I can have the post commit hook send out an email every time someone checks something, but can I limit that to only if people check something into the tags directory?  Basically I want a notification when anyone promotes a release.  My subversion is running on Windows.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You get the repo and revision that was committed as the arguments to the post-commit hook.

Use `svnlook` to get the path of the files changed in the revision and see if it has `tags` and trigger your email.

```
 svnlook changed -r $rev $repo
```

The above will give lines that look like

```
A   trunk/app/file.cs
```

Use that info to see if tag was added and write you post-commit

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the first argument to the post-commit script is the repository path; look for `<whatever>/tags` in there, and only send email if you find it.

Comment: repo path is local repository path on the server! It has nothing to do with the url